# Remove starting command from .profile

Tags: bash, zsh, profile

[image]

Where can be command that produces this error?

These are my dot files:

```
echo .*
.3T .CFUserTextEncoding .Rapp.history .Trash .android .angular-config.json .atom .atomic .babel.json .bash_history .bash_profile .bash_sessions .bundle .cache .cargo .cocoapods .config .docker .electron .expo .gem .ghc .gitconfig .gitflow_export .gitignore_global .gradle .hgignore_global .ievms .konan .lesshst .local .netrc .node-gyp .node_repl_history .npm .npm-global .npmrc .nvm .oracle_jre_usage .profile .react-native-cli .rustup .ssh .travis .viminfo .vscode .yarnrc .zprofile .zsh_history .zshrc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it.

It is. `.zshrc`

I added this line to be sure next time:

`echo "Hello zsh";`

Comment: Can you please accept your own answer, so this question doesn't stay open?